# How to dynamically add/delete table rows in ReacjJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbreact

I am trying to dynamically add and delete `table` rows using `ReactJS`.
But the problem is once I added few rows, the values in each column in each rows are the same even if I change them randomly.

Below screen shot will clarify further of my problem.

[image: screenshot]

The steps of what I am trying to do is:

1) Select an `item` from the dropdown

2) Enter the `qty`

3) Press `+` button

**It works, but the next time I try to select an item or enter the quantity for an item, it `updates every column`**

This is my code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  MDBRow,
  MDBCol,
  MDBCard,
  MDBCardBody,
  MDBMask,
  MDBIcon,
  MDBView,
  MDBBtn,
  MDBTable,
  MDBTableBody,
  MDBTableHead,
  MDBContainer
} from "mdbreact";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import GetTable from "./table";
import GetTable2 from "./table2";

export default class CreateInvoiceForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      vendorName: "",
      itemID: "",
      qty: "",
      rows: [{}]
    };

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.vendorOnChange = this.vendorOnChange.bind(this);
    this.itemorOnChange = this.itemorOnChange.bind(this);
    this.quantityOnChange = this.quantityOnChange.bind(this);
    this.onHandleAddRow = this.onHandleAddRow.bind(this);
  }

  onHandleAddRow() {
    const itemDetails = {
      itemID: this.state.itemID,
      itemName: "",
      qty: this.state.qty,
      unitPrice: "",
      linePrice: ""
    };

    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, itemDetails]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.state.vendorName);
  }

  vendorOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      vendorName: e.target.value
    });
  }

  quantityOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      qty: e.target.value
    });
  }

  itemorOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      itemID: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MDBCard className="my-12 px-12 pb-12">
          <MDBCardBody className="">
            <h2 className="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-5">
              Create a Purchase Invoice
            </h2>
            <p className="text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">
              Creating purchase invoices
              <strong>Without having a Purchase Order</strong>
            </p>

            {/* form starts here */}
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol lg="6" md="6" className="mb-lg-0 mb-6">
                  <p className="h6 mb-4">
                    {" "}
                    <i className="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Invoice Details
                  </p>
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterNameEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Invoice No:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterNameEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Vendor
                  </label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select
                      class="form-control"
                      id="exampleSelect1"
                      onChange={this.vendorOnChange}
                    >
                      <option disabled selected>
                        - Select vendor -{" "}
                      </option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterConfirmEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Invoice Date:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterConfirmEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterPasswordEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Expected Delievery Date:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterPasswordEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol lg="6" md="6" className="mb-lg-0 mb-6">
                  <p className="h6 mb-4">
                    {" "}
                    <i className="fa fa-truck"></i> Delievery Details
                  </p>
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterNameEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Billing Address
                  </label>
                  <textarea className="form-control"> </textarea>

                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  >
                    Contact Person:
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterConfirmEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  ></label>
                  <input
                    hidden
                    type="email"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterConfirmEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <label
                    htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterPasswordEx"
                    className="grey-text"
                  ></label>
                  <input
                    hidden
                    type="password"
                    id="defaultFormRegisterPasswordEx"
                    className="form-control"
                  />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                </MDBCol>
              </MDBRow>
              <hr />
              {/* new row======================================================= */}

              <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol lg="5" md="5" className="mb-lg-0 mb-5 text-center">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                      className="grey-text"
                    >
                      Select an Item:
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" onChange={this.itemorOnChange}>
                      <option disabled selected>
                        - Select Item -
                      </option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol lg="5" md="5" className="mb-lg-0 mb-5 text-center">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                      className="grey-text"
                    >
                      Quantity:
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.quantityOnChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol lg="2" md="2" className="mb-lg-0 mb-2 text-center">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="defaultFormRegisterEmailEx"
                      className="grey-text"
                    ></label>
                    <button
                      style={{ height: "40px" }}
                      name="subject"
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success btn-sm form-control"
                      onClick={this.onHandleAddRow}
                    >
                      <i className="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </MDBCol>
              </MDBRow>

              <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol lg="12" md="12" className="mb-lg-0 mb-12 text-center">
                  <MDBTable
                    className="container-fluid"
                    striped
                    bordered
                    hover
                    responsive
                  >
                    <MDBTableHead color="primary-color" textWhite>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Item ID</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Unit Price (R.s)</th>
                        <th>Line Price (R.s)</th>
                        <th><i className="fa fa-cog"></i></th>
                      </tr>
                    </MDBTableHead>
                    <MDBTableBody>

                        {this.state.rows.length > 1
                        ? this.state.rows.map((item, id) => (
                          <tr key={id}>
                            <td>{this.state.itemID}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.itemID}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.qty}</td>
                            <td>price</td>
                            <td>Line</td>
                            <MDBBtn><i className="fa fa-times"></i></MDBBtn>
                          </tr>
                        ))
                        : <tr></tr>
                        }
                    </MDBTableBody>
                  </MDBTable>
                </MDBCol>
              </MDBRow>
            </form>
            {/* form ends here */}
          </MDBCardBody>
        </MDBCard>
        <br />
        <MDBContainer>
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol className="col-12 col-md-12 text-center">
              <GetTable2 />
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>
        </MDBContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single state value for `qty` and `itemID` so it'll render every row with a single value. If you need a quantity and item ID for each item (which seems reasonable) then you need to keep that in state *per item*.

Your `map` should be changed to use the value from each row, e.g., `item.qty` (oddly a string), and your quantity update should change that row's data.

Comment: How can I keep a separate state for each and every item? Can you give me an example?

Comment: ... You already *have* state for every item, that's what `rows` is. You just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props) //since we are extending class Table so we have to use super in order to override Component class constructor
      this.state = { //state is by default an object
         students: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' }
         ]
      }
   }

   render() { //Whenever our class runs, render method will be called automatically, it may have already defined in the constructor behind the scene.
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>React Dynamic Table</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Table //exporting a component make it reusable and this is the beauty of react
```

Comment: This isn't helpful as-is. Unrelated, but it's not "whenever our class runs", it's when its state or props change, which you don't show. Answers should directly address the question; while creating a table component might help, it's unrelated to the question.